# Search, identify primary key and return results from multiple tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

In my code I can only search a table and return a few things from one table, but from the posted value last name, how do I get 'emp_no' so that I can return 'dept_no' from 'dept_emp' and 'title' from 'titles'?

the controller

```
public function findemp() 
{   
    // search in table 'employees'
    $name = $this->input->get('lastname');


    if($data['user'] = $this->fndmodel->finduser($name)) {

        $this->load->view('searchview', $data);
    }

    // search in table 'dept_emp'
    $dept = $this->input->get('deptmnt');
    // search in table 'titles'
    $title = $this->input->get('title');
}
```

the model

```
 public function finduser($name) {

    if ($name == null || $name == '') {
            return false;
    }

    $this->db->select('e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.title, d.dept_no');
    $this->db->from('employees AS e, titles AS t, dept_emp AS d');
    $this->db->where('e.emp_no = t.emp_no');
    $this->db->where('e.emp_no = d.emp_no');
    $this->db->where('e.last_name', $name);
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get();              
    return $data;

}
```

This is what I would like in activerecords

```
SELECT e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.title, d.dept_no
FROM employees e JOIN titles t
ON (e.emp_no = t.emp_no)
JOIN dept_emp d
ON (e.emp_no = d.emp_no)
WHERE e.last_name = "facello";
```

Is this right?

```
$this->db->select('e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.title, d.dept_no');
$this->db->from('employees AS e, titles AS t, dept_emp AS d');
$this->db->where('e.emp_no = t.emp_no');
$this->db->where('e.emp_no = d.emp_no');
$this->db->where('e.last_name', $name);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: **join** and a **subquery**. just a hint. Reaibalty will be better with raw query than the query builder because you will need a library if you want to go the subquery way.

Comment: Ok, could you look at the edit I've made and help me convert this into  activerecords?